# how to use 2 android themes in android manifist?

Tags: android-manifest, android-theme

i try to use 2 themes in one activity,one for dialog and one for hiding the title bar, in the AndroidManifest:

```
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"

        android:label="@string/app_name" > (it show X here!!)
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

i can only use one at a time...

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom theme and apply all style you want in it and set that theme as theme of your manifest or of your activity. For example :

Make a xml file in values folder named customtheme.xml as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground </item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">@dimen/custom_title_bar_h</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="ptrHeaderStyle">@style/Widget.Custom.PtrHeader</item>

    <!-- <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall</item> -->
</style>

<style name="WindowTitleBackground">
    <item name="android:padding">0px</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_bg</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Custom.PtrHeader" parent="android:Widget">

    <!-- The background of the header view -->
    <item name="ptrHeaderBackground">@drawable/action_bar_bg</item>

    <!-- The height of the header view. Please note, only set if in you really need to -->
    <item name="ptrHeaderHeight">@dimen/custom_title_bar_h</item>
    <item name="ptrHeaderTitleTextColor">@color/white</item>

</style>
</resources>
```

Now set that theme to your activity :

```
        <activity
              android:name=".SettingsActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
              android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >
        </activity>
```